# Weird JS Behavior With Bootstrap Sliders

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

So I recieved help from an internet saint to vastly improve my code to create a bootstrap slider per list item within a JS for loop, but now it is behaving erratically.

Sometimes it works perfectly, others it creates new items but not sliders (just a text input field), and others it only creates one item per list.

[image: Sample Image]

Any great minds see where I'm going wrong?

```js
var proArray = [];
 function addPro() {
     var val = document.getElementById("proInput").value.trim();
     document.getElementById("proForm").reset();
     if (val.length == 0) {
         return;
     }
     if (document.getElementById('proInput' + val) == null) {
         proArray.push({id: val, slider: null});
     } else {
         return;
     }
     for (var i = 0; i < proArray.length; i++) {
         var ele = document.getElementById('proInput' + proArray[i].id);
         if (ele == null) {
             var newItem = "<li><p>" + proArray[i].id + "</p><input class='bootstrap-slider' type='text' value='' id='proInput" +
                     proArray[i].id + "' data-slider-id='SIDproInput" + proArray[i].id
                     + "' data-slider-min='0' data-slider-max='10' data-slider-value='5'/></li>";
             document.getElementById("proList").innerHTML += newItem;
             proArray[i].slider = new Slider('#proInput' + proArray[i].id, {
                 formatter: function(value) {
                     return 'Current value: ' + value;
                 }
             });
         } else {
             (function(i) {
                 setTimeout(function() {
                     var val = proArray[i].slider.getValue();
                     proArray[i].slider.destroy();
                     document.getElementById('SIDproInput' + proArray[i].id).remove();
                     proArray[i].slider = new Slider('#proInput' + proArray[i].id, {
                         formatter: function (value) {
                             return 'Current value: ' + value;
                         }
                     });
                     proArray[i].slider.setValue(val);
                 }, 100);
             })(i);
         }
     }
 }

 var conArray = [];
 function addCon() {
     var valCon = document.getElementById("conInput").value.trim();
     document.getElementById("conForm").reset();
     if (valCon.length == 0) {
         return;
     }
     if (document.getElementById('conInput' + valCon) == null) {
         conArray.push({id: valCon, slider: null});
     } else {
         return;
     }
     for (var i = 0; i < conArray.length; i++) {
         var ele = document.getElementById('conInput' + conArray[i].id);
         if (ele == null) {
             var newItem = "<li><p>" + conArray[i].id + "</p><input class='bootstrap-slider' type='text' value='' id='conInput" +
                     conArray[i].id + "' data-slider-id='SIDconInput" + conArray[i].id
                     + "' data-slider-min='0' data-slider-max='10' data-slider-value='5'/></li>";
             document.getElementById("conList").innerHTML += newItem;
             conArray[i].slider = new Slider('#conInput' + conArray[i].id, {
                 formatter: function(value) {
                     return 'Current value: ' + value;
                 }
             });
         } else {
             (function(i) {
                 setTimeout(function() {
                     var valCon = conArray[i].slider.getValue();
                     conArray[i].slider.destroy();
                     document.getElementById('SIDconInput' + conArray[i].id).remove();
                     conArray[i].slider = new Slider('#conInput' + conArray[i].id, {
                         formatter: function (value) {
                             return 'Current value: ' + value;
                         }
                     });
                     conArray[i].slider.setValue(valCon);
                 }, 100);
             })(i);
         }
     }
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.7.3/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.7.3/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-6">
      <h2>Pros</h2>
      <p>The Good Stuff</p>
      <form id="proForm" onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;">
       <input class="form-control text-left pro-con-input" id="proInput" placeholder="Add New Benefit"/>
       <div onclick="addPro()" class="btn pro-con-btn">Add</div>
   </form>
   <h3 class="text-left">Benefits</h3>
   <ul class="text-left" id="proList">
   </ul>
     </div> <!-- pros -->

     <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h2>Cons</h2>
      <p>The Bad Stuff</p>
      <form id="conForm" onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;">
       <input class="form-control text-left pro-con-input" id="conInput" placeholder="Add New Benefit"/>
       <div onclick="addCon()" class="btn pro-con-btn">Add</div>
   </form>
   <h3 class="text-left">Costs</h3>
   <ul class="text-left" id="conList">
   </ul>
     </div> <!-- cons -->
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your browser console? Seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: You have a lot of external files being loaded... probably some conflict is happening. try rearranging the order of those css and js files, also try commenting out each one at a time, to isolate issue further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have two lists you can use two arrays:

- var proArray = [];
- var conArray = [];

The inline functions can be changed in order to pass the list prefix as parameter:

- newAdd('pro')
- newAdd('con')

And so you can adjust the addPro function to these changes.

From comment:

> If I type in "@" or "?" as an item in your snippet above it shows the error. Not for you?

In order to solve such an issue you need to escape those chars when creating the slider:

```
arr[i].slider = new Slider('#' + listIdPrefix + 'Input' +
         arr[i].id.replace(/@/g, '\\@').replace(/\?/g, '\\?').....
```

The snippet:

```js
var proArray = [];
var conArray = [];
function newAdd(listIdPrefix) {
    var val = document.getElementById(listIdPrefix + "Input").value.trim();
    document.getElementById(listIdPrefix + "Form").reset();
    if (val.length == 0) {
        return;
    }
    var arr;
    if (document.getElementById(listIdPrefix + 'Input' + val) == null) {
        if (listIdPrefix == 'pro') {
            proArray.push({id: val, slider: null});
            arr = proArray;
        } else {
            conArray.push({id: val, slider: null});
            arr = conArray;
        }
    } else {
        return;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var ele = document.getElementById(listIdPrefix + 'Input' + arr[i].id);
        if (ele == null) {
            var newItem = "<li><p>" + arr[i].id + "</p><input class='bootstrap-slider' type='text' value='' id='" + listIdPrefix + "Input" +
                    arr[i].id + "' data-slider-id='SID" + listIdPrefix + "Input" + arr[i].id
                    + "' data-slider-min='0' data-slider-max='10' data-slider-value='5'/></li>";
            document.getElementById(listIdPrefix + "List").innerHTML += newItem;
            arr[i].slider = new Slider('#' + listIdPrefix + 'Input' + arr[i].id.replace(/@/g, '\\@').replace(/\?/g, '\\?').replace(/\./g, '\\.'), {
                formatter: function (value) {
                    return 'Current value: ' + value;
                }
            });
        } else {
            (function (i, arr) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    var val = arr[i].slider.getValue();
                    arr[i].slider.destroy();
                    document.getElementById('SID' + listIdPrefix + 'Input' + arr[i].id).remove();
                    arr[i].slider = new Slider('#' + listIdPrefix + 'Input' + arr[i].id.replace(/@/g, '\\@').replace(/\?/g, '\\?').replace(/\./g, '\\.'), {
                        formatter: function (value) {
                            return 'Current value: ' + value;
                        }
                    });
                    arr[i].slider.setValue(val);
                }, 100);
            })(i, arr);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.7.3/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.7.3/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>


<div class="col-sm-6">
    <h2>Pros</h2>
    <p>The Good Stuff</p>
    <form id="proForm" onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;">
        <input class="form-control text-left pro-con-input" id="proInput" placeholder="Add New Benefit"/>
        <div onclick="newAdd('pro')" class="btn pro-con-btn">Add</div>
    </form>
    <h3 class="text-left">Benefits</h3>
    <ul class="text-left" id="proList">
    </ul>
</div> <!-- pros -->

<div class="col-sm-6">
    <h2>Cons</h2>
    <p>The Bad Stuff</p>
    <form id="conForm" onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;">
        <input class="form-control text-left pro-con-input" id="conInput" placeholder="Add New Benefit"/>
        <div onclick="newAdd('con')" class="btn pro-con-btn">Add</div>
    </form>
    <h3 class="text-left">Costs</h3>
    <ul class="text-left" id="conList">
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Every once in a while it still gets a weird `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null` error.

Comment: It might have to do with items that have punctuation or spaces.

Comment: If I type in "@" or "?" as an item in your snippet above it shows the error.  Not for you?

Comment: @Liz When creating the slider you need to escape special chars: arr[i].id.replace(/@/g, '\\@').replace(/\?/g, '\\?'). Snippet updated. Let me know.

Comment: Beautiful!  Thank you for being my JS-for-Dummies helper!

Comment: @Liz Thanks so much